# Misalignment in frame break in LaTeX presentation

Tags: beamer

How can I split the frame in multiple parts? when I use `allowbreakframes` command, it hide my text and just show the figures. Please Help me.

MWE:

```
\begin{document} 

\subsection{Decimation} 

\begin{frame} 

\frametitle{Decimation}
\pause 
Decimation is achieved first by passing a signal from anti aliasing filter. 
\begin{figure}[hbtp] 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../../Desktop/figures/Mutlirate 1.jpg} 
  \caption{Down-Sampling} 
\end{figure}
\pause 
%\end{equation} 

\begin{figure}[hbtp] 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{../../Desktop/figures/Mutlirate 2.jpg} 
  \caption{Sinousoidal Signal} 
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[hbtp] 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{../../Desktop/figures/Mutlirate 3.jpg} 
  \caption{Down-sampling of Sine wave} 
\end{figure} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to have a slide split into two for figures and text? In this case I'd use columns:

```
\begin{columns}[c]
    \column{.5\textwidth}
       Left Column
    \column{.5\textwidth}
       Right Column
\end{columns}
```